# Form inside angular component does not submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have a classic html form element which works fine when I insert it into the index.html of an angular application. A click on the button submits the form. If I insert the same form in an angular component html file, it is rendered as well but when I click the button, nothing happens.

```
  <form method="post" action="https://blub.shtml" id="form" name="form" target="_parent">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="data" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I cant use `(ngSubmit)` because of the CORS policy of the server.

Comment: Why do you want to put a form in index.html ?

Comment: I dont want to put it in the index.html. I want it in the component. Its just that it works if I test it inside the index.html.

Comment: What is the error you have when put in the component ? Or just wont work

Comment: There is no error, nothing happens on click.

Comment: I think you should remove `target="_parent"`

Comment: You should config CORS on the server

Comment: Its not my server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach to see if it work

```
  <form method="post" action="https://blub.shtml" id="form" name="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="data" />
    <button type="submit"/>Send</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #form="ngForm">
```

and in onSubimit method you can to whaterver you want.

Comment: This way onSubmit is triggered but unfortunately I get CORS errors when posting the form via an ajax request, so I cant use it.

Comment: @ynotu this is not your question. I give you the solution for your question but now if it gives you a CORS you have resolve anoher problem but my solution is correct because if the program gives you CORS the form is submitted and my answer is correct.

Comment: @ynotu. no this is a wrong behavior.  You must give me "correct answer" and after you must pusblisher another question.